# How to vertically center the text contained in merged table cells?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rotating

I've been struggling with a table for a while now, where I have three columns with some merged cells and I'd like to be able to center the text vertically (in columns 3 to 5) and make better usagee of the space.

In the case of the text in the first column, I've tried to rotate it 90 degrees but I can't manage to center the text so that I can make better use of the internal space of the cells.

I have tried with the `rotating` and `graphicx` packages as I have seen recommended in some previous questions but without a satisfactory result. That's why I've decided to ask directly hoping that this is not a duplicate question.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
%\usepackage{graphicx}    
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{Criterios de selección para los casos sospechosos de COVID-19}
  \label{tab:critsospcovid}
  \centering{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{p{0.08\linewidth}p{0.45\linewidth}p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.15\linewidth}}
      \toprule
      Historia epidemiológica &% 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene un historial de viajes o residencia en
  las regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene antecedentes de contacto con personas
  infectadas con el SARS-CoV-2 (aquellos con un resultado positivo de
  PAN);
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tuvo contacto directo con pacientes con
  fiebre o síntomas respiratorios en regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Agrupación de enfermedades (2 ó más casos con fiebre y/o
  síntomas respiratorios ocurren en lugares como casas, oficinas,
  aulas escolares, etc. en un plazo de 2 semanas).
\end{enumerate} & \multirow[c]{2}{\linewidth}{El paciente cumple 1 historia epidemiológica y 2 manifestaciones clínicas.} & \multirow[c]{2}{\linewidth}{El paciente no tiene antecedentes epidemiológicos y cumple con 3 manifestaciones clínicas.} & \multirow[c]{2}{\linewidth}{El paciente no tiene historia epidemiológica, cumple 1-2 manifestaciones clínicas, pero no puede excluirse de COVID-19 a través de imagenología.} \\
      \cmidrule{1-2} Manifestaciones clínicas &%
                                                \begin{enumerate}
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene fiebre y/o
                                                  síntomas
                                                  respiratorios;
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene las siguientes
                                                  características de
                                                  la imagen de TC de
                                                  COVID-19: múltiples
                                                  sombras parchadas y
                                                  cambios
                                                  intersticiales
                                                  ocurren temprano,
                                                  particularmente en
                                                  la periferia del
                                                  pulmón. Las
                                                  condiciones se
                                                  convierten en
                                                  múltiples opacidades
                                                  e infiltraciones en
                                                  ambos pulmones. En
                                                  casos graves, el
                                                  paciente puede tener
                                                  congestión pulmonar
                                                  y un raro derrame
                                                  pleural;
                                                \item El recuento de
                                                  glóbulos blancos en
                                                  la etapa inicial de
                                                  la enfermedad es
                                                  normal o está
                                                  disminuido, o el
                                                  recuento de
                                                  linfocitos disminuye
                                                  con el tiempo.
                                                \end{enumerate} & & & \\
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Diagnóstico de casos sospechosos} & Sí & Sí & Asesoría de expertos \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be ok with rotating the whole table to a landscape oriented page?

Answer (score 2):

Here are 4 versions of your table. I have used a customized `enumerate`-like environment in order to remove the white space above and below the enumerate items. In order to save even more space, I have entirely removed the first column and placed the corresponding text directly above the corresponding enumerate environments.

The first two examples are on portrait pages with the text in the last three columns top aligned or centered, while the third and last example show the same vertical alignments of the last columns but on a landscape page. Personally, I would prefer table 3:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
%\usepackage{graphicx}    
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate,1]{nosep,leftmargin=3\tabcolsep,,after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip},label*=\arabic*.,}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{Criterios de selección para los casos sospechosos de COVID-19}
  \label{tab:critsospcovid1}
  \centering{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{p{0.55\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
      \toprule
      Historia epidemiológica % 
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene un historial de viajes o residencia en
  las regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene antecedentes de contacto con personas
  infectadas con el SARS-CoV-2 (aquellos con un resultado positivo de
  PAN);
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tuvo contacto directo con pacientes con
  fiebre o síntomas respiratorios en regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Agrupación de enfermedades (2 ó más casos con fiebre y/o
  síntomas respiratorios ocurren en lugares como casas, oficinas,
  aulas escolares, etc. en un plazo de 2 semanas).
\end{tabenumerate} 
& El paciente cumple 1 historia epidemiológica y 2 manifestaciones clínicas. 
& El paciente no tiene antecedentes epidemiológicos y cumple con 3 manifestaciones clínicas. 
& El paciente no tiene historia epidemiológica, cumple 1-2 manifestaciones clínicas, pero no puede excluirse de COVID-19 a través de imagenología. \\
      \cmidrule{1-1} Manifestaciones clínicas %
                                                \begin{tabenumerate}
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene fiebre y/o
                                                  síntomas
                                                  respiratorios;
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene las siguientes
                                                  características de
                                                  la imagen de TC de
                                                  COVID-19: múltiples
                                                  sombras parchadas y
                                                  cambios
                                                  intersticiales
                                                  ocurren temprano,
                                                  particularmente en
                                                  la periferia del
                                                  pulmón. Las
                                                  condiciones se
                                                  convierten en
                                                  múltiples opacidades
                                                  e infiltraciones en
                                                  ambos pulmones. En
                                                  casos graves, el
                                                  paciente puede tener
                                                  congestión pulmonar
                                                  y un raro derrame
                                                  pleural;
                                                \item El recuento de
                                                  glóbulos blancos en
                                                  la etapa inicial de
                                                  la enfermedad es
                                                  normal o está
                                                  disminuido, o el
                                                  recuento de
                                                  linfocitos disminuye
                                                  con el tiempo.
                                                \end{tabenumerate} & & & \\
      \midrule
      Diagnóstico de casos sospechosos & Sí & Sí & Asesoría de expertos \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{Criterios de selección para los casos sospechosos de COVID-19}
  \label{tab:critsospcovid2}
  \centering{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{p{0.55\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
      \toprule
      Historia epidemiológica % 
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene un historial de viajes o residencia en
  las regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene antecedentes de contacto con personas
  infectadas con el SARS-CoV-2 (aquellos con un resultado positivo de
  PAN);
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tuvo contacto directo con pacientes con
  fiebre o síntomas respiratorios en regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Agrupación de enfermedades (2 ó más casos con fiebre y/o
  síntomas respiratorios ocurren en lugares como casas, oficinas,
  aulas escolares, etc. en un plazo de 2 semanas).
\end{tabenumerate} 
& \multirow[c]{31.5}{=}{El paciente cumple 1 historia epidemiológica y 2 manifestaciones clínicas.} 
& \multirow[c]{31.5}{=}{El paciente no tiene antecedentes epidemiológicos y cumple con 3 manifestaciones clínicas.} 
& \multirow[c]{31.5}{=}{El paciente no tiene historia epidemiológica, cumple 1-2 manifestaciones clínicas, pero no puede excluirse de COVID-19 a través de imagenología.} \\
      \cmidrule{1-1} Manifestaciones clínicas %
                                                \begin{tabenumerate}
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene fiebre y/o
                                                  síntomas
                                                  respiratorios;
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene las siguientes
                                                  características de
                                                  la imagen de TC de
                                                  COVID-19: múltiples
                                                  sombras parchadas y
                                                  cambios
                                                  intersticiales
                                                  ocurren temprano,
                                                  particularmente en
                                                  la periferia del
                                                  pulmón. Las
                                                  condiciones se
                                                  convierten en
                                                  múltiples opacidades
                                                  e infiltraciones en
                                                  ambos pulmones. En
                                                  casos graves, el
                                                  paciente puede tener
                                                  congestión pulmonar
                                                  y un raro derrame
                                                  pleural;
                                                \item El recuento de
                                                  glóbulos blancos en
                                                  la etapa inicial de
                                                  la enfermedad es
                                                  normal o está
                                                  disminuido, o el
                                                  recuento de
                                                  linfocitos disminuye
                                                  con el tiempo.
                                                \end{tabenumerate} & & & \\
      \midrule
      Diagnóstico de casos sospechosos & Sí & Sí & Asesoría de expertos \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}




\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{Criterios de selección para los casos sospechosos de COVID-19}
  \label{tab:critsospcovid3}
  \centering{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{p{0.625\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.125\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
      \toprule
      Historia epidemiológica % 
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene un historial de viajes o residencia en
  las regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene antecedentes de contacto con personas
  infectadas con el SARS-CoV-2 (aquellos con un resultado positivo de
  PAN);
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tuvo contacto directo con pacientes con
  fiebre o síntomas respiratorios en regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Agrupación de enfermedades (2 ó más casos con fiebre y/o
  síntomas respiratorios ocurren en lugares como casas, oficinas,
  aulas escolares, etc. en un plazo de 2 semanas).
\end{tabenumerate} 
& El paciente cumple 1 historia epidemiológica y 2 manifestaciones clínicas. 
& El paciente no tiene antecedentes epidemiológicos y cumple con 3 manifestaciones clínicas. 
& El paciente no tiene historia epidemiológica, cumple 1-2 manifestaciones clínicas, pero no puede excluirse de COVID-19 a través de imagenología. \\
      \cmidrule{1-1} Manifestaciones clínicas %
                                                \begin{tabenumerate}
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene fiebre y/o
                                                  síntomas
                                                  respiratorios;
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene las siguientes
                                                  características de
                                                  la imagen de TC de
                                                  COVID-19: múltiples
                                                  sombras parchadas y
                                                  cambios
                                                  intersticiales
                                                  ocurren temprano,
                                                  particularmente en
                                                  la periferia del
                                                  pulmón. Las
                                                  condiciones se
                                                  convierten en
                                                  múltiples opacidades
                                                  e infiltraciones en
                                                  ambos pulmones. En
                                                  casos graves, el
                                                  paciente puede tener
                                                  congestión pulmonar
                                                  y un raro derrame
                                                  pleural;
                                                \item El recuento de
                                                  glóbulos blancos en
                                                  la etapa inicial de
                                                  la enfermedad es
                                                  normal o está
                                                  disminuido, o el
                                                  recuento de
                                                  linfocitos disminuye
                                                  con el tiempo.
                                                \end{tabenumerate} & & & \\
      \midrule
      Diagnóstico de casos sospechosos & Sí & Sí & Asesoría de expertos \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{Criterios de selección para los casos sospechosos de COVID-19}
  \label{tab:critsospcovid4}
  \centering{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{p{0.625\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}*{3}{p{0.125\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
      \toprule
      Historia epidemiológica % 
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene un historial de viajes o residencia en
  las regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tiene antecedentes de contacto con personas
  infectadas con el SARS-CoV-2 (aquellos con un resultado positivo de
  PAN);
\item Dentro de los 14 días anteriores a la aparición de la
  enfermedad, el paciente tuvo contacto directo con pacientes con
  fiebre o síntomas respiratorios en regiones o países de alto riesgo;
\item Agrupación de enfermedades (2 ó más casos con fiebre y/o
  síntomas respiratorios ocurren en lugares como casas, oficinas,
  aulas escolares, etc. en un plazo de 2 semanas).
\end{tabenumerate} 
& \multirow[c]{21.5}{=}{El paciente cumple 1 historia epidemiológica y 2 manifestaciones clínicas.} 
& \multirow[c]{21.5}{=}{El paciente no tiene antecedentes epidemiológicos y cumple con 3 manifestaciones clínicas.} 
& \multirow[c]{21.5}{=}{El paciente no tiene historia epidemiológica, cumple 1-2 manifestaciones clínicas, pero no puede excluirse de COVID-19 a través de imagenología.} \\
      \cmidrule{1-1} Manifestaciones clínicas %
                                                \begin{tabenumerate}
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene fiebre y/o
                                                  síntomas
                                                  respiratorios;
                                                \item El paciente
                                                  tiene las siguientes
                                                  características de
                                                  la imagen de TC de
                                                  COVID-19: múltiples
                                                  sombras parchadas y
                                                  cambios
                                                  intersticiales
                                                  ocurren temprano,
                                                  particularmente en
                                                  la periferia del
                                                  pulmón. Las
                                                  condiciones se
                                                  convierten en
                                                  múltiples opacidades
                                                  e infiltraciones en
                                                  ambos pulmones. En
                                                  casos graves, el
                                                  paciente puede tener
                                                  congestión pulmonar
                                                  y un raro derrame
                                                  pleural;
                                                \item El recuento de
                                                  glóbulos blancos en
                                                  la etapa inicial de
                                                  la enfermedad es
                                                  normal o está
                                                  disminuido, o el
                                                  recuento de
                                                  linfocitos disminuye
                                                  con el tiempo.
                                                \end{tabenumerate} & & & \\
      \midrule
      Diagnóstico de casos sospechosos & Sí & Sí & Asesoría de expertos \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing, very good proposals, I like 3 and 4, but in all cases the first column is lost whose text I have to rotate 90° counterclockwise and center it which is what is asked of me, I will see if any of these proposals pass.